# Keep duplicate rows after the first but save the index of the first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to find duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe, but keep track of the index of the original duplicate.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[1,4],[1,2]],columns=['col1','col2'])

df
Out[15]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
2     1     2
3     1     4
4     1     2

duplicate_bool = df.duplicated(subset=['col1','col2'], keep='first')
duplicate = df.loc[duplicate_bool == True]

duplicate
Out[16]: 
   col1  col2
2     1     2
4     1     2
```

Is there a way to add a column referring to the index of the first duplicate (the one kept)

```
duplicate
Out[16]: 
   col1  col2  index_original
2     1     2               0
4     1     2               0
```

Note: df could be very very big in my case....

Comment: What if there are 3 duplicates?

Comment: good point! I edited the question

Comment: Could you add ouput for different duplicates than only one.

Comment: how can I do if I have 90 columns?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `groupby`, create a new column of indexes, and then call `duplicated`:

```
df['index_original'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col1.transform('idxmin')    
df[df.duplicated(subset=['col1','col2'], keep='first')]

   col1  col2  index_original
2     1     2               0
4     1     2               0
```

---

**Details**

I `groupby` first two columns and then call `transform` + `idxmin` to get the first index of each group.

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col1.transform('idxmin') 

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    3
4    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

`duplicated` gives me a boolean mask of values I want to keep:

```
df.duplicated(subset=['col1','col2'], keep='first')

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

The rest is just *boolean indexing*.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hi, the solution works perfectly fine for the example, however when I try to apply it to my real case it takes forever... the size is (11861200,2)

Comment: @gabboshow 11 million rows? That's scary as hell.... you should try parallelising your groupby operation with `dask`, you can work with huge dataframes that way.

Comment: still I think it will be quite slow... is there a way to not use groupby or this is the fastest solution?

Comment: @gabboshow If you're using pandas.... no better way strikes me than using groupby... you could try asking a similar question in the `numpy` tag and see if divakar has a numpy solution for you... (he might).

Comment: @cs95 how can I do if I have 90 columns?

Answer (score 11):

May you don't need this answer anymore but there's another way to find duplicated rows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[1,4],[1,2]],columns=['col1','col2'])
```

Given the above DataFrame you can use groupby with no drama but with larger DataFrames it'll be kinda slow, instead of that you can use

> DataFrame.duplicated(subset=None, keep='first')
>
> Return boolean Series denoting duplicate rows.

As the [documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) says, it returns a boolean series, in other words, a boolean mask, so you can manipulate the DataFrame with that mask, or just visualize the repeated rows:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated()]
   col1  col2
2     1     2
4     1     2
```

if you have a DataFrame with more columns and you want to find duplicated rows by specific columns, you can give to the function a list of columns to look for, for example to the following DataFrame:

```
# List of Tuples
students = [('jack', 34, 'Sydeny'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Aadi', 16, 'New York'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Mumbai'),
            ('Aadi', 40, 'London'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi')
            ]
# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
```

if you want to find the duplicated rows by all columns and visualize it, just do:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated()]
   Name  Age   City
3  Riti   30  Delhi
4  Riti   30  Delhi
```

but if you want to just look for duplicated rows taking into account only two columns, for example, 'Name' and  'Age' just do:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(['Name', 'Age'])]
   Name  Age    City
3  Riti   30   Delhi
4  Riti   30   Delhi
5  Riti   30  Mumbai
```

Or just one column like 'Name':

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(['Name'])]
   Name  Age    City
3  Riti   30   Delhi
4  Riti   30   Delhi
5  Riti   30  Mumbai
6  Aadi   40  London
```

The above examples just returned the repeated rows, not the 'original one' so if you look the examples, if there are three repeated rows by a given criteria, just two will be returned.

Comment: Great effort! and sure is faster for bigger dataframes. +10 :)

Comment: `keep="first"` threw me off--`keep=False` just returns all of the duplicate rows without tossing out the first. I understand that's not OP's goal, but might be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

```
len(df[df.duplicated()])
```

By this method, you can count the number of duplicates in your dataset.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.