# Know which row is similar with the another in a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which is called data.
Also, I have 2057 columns and 197 rows in dataframe group1, I want to know which row is similar to another one.
I made this:

```
group1=pd.crosstab(data.column1,data.column2)
 group1["EsDuplicado?"]=group1.duplicated(subset=group1.columns.difference(['BCP_Nombre_de_la_Matriz__c']),keep=False)
```

Until now it's working, and I added a new column with value is true(when the row is similar to another one) or false when the row is not similar.

I want To know which rows are similar and know exactly its pair.

Until now my table is like this:

[image]

But I would want something like this:

[image]

Or maybe this is not necessary, and maybe it's enough if the rows are next to each other, in that way I know which row is similar.

I want something like this, but in this example is only 2 column in my case I have 2057 columns:

[find duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. If you're using Pandas, please make sure to add the [tag:pandas] tag.

Comment: I'm unclear if you want to find distinct rows and match them based on equivalent values in all column of a row OR match them based on a common column value.

Comment: @DavidErickson each row have different values in the columns for example row1 have in column1 3, in column2 4, in column3 5,etc. So I know there are rows that have the same values that row 1. So I want to know which rows are similar. Maybe row100 is similar with row400 because its columns are similar, something like thist.Is it more clear now? please tell me if not, to be more clear. Thanks, in advance. It's first time that I am using this.

Comment: @DavidErickson I want something like this. But I have more columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: In the answer to the question you linked to, `['col1', 'col2']` is the list of relevant columns. So have you tried using that same groupby approach, just replacing `['col1', 'col2']` with the full list of your columns?

Comment: @Arne Hi, thanks for your comment. Actually I tried, but they are so many columns, Do I need to write one by one? I made a List of the columns and did something like this: df['index_original'] = df.groupby([ListOfColumns]).col1.transform('idxmin') , and appears and error apparently because I did not define 'col1', So I am not sure if it's possible to put a list in groupby and also don't know what to put in 'col1' , the name of my first column? because I put it and happened the same

Comment: @FERNANDO FERNANDEZ I wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @cs95 to the question you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe) to can straightforwardly be generalized to any number of columns.

Here's a small example dataset for testing, but I'll make the second code block general, so that it should also work for your DataFrame, as long as its name is `group1`.

```py
import pandas as pd

group1 = pd.DataFrame({'column 1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                       'column 2': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                       'column 3': [3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4]})
group1
```

```py
    column 1    column 2    column 3
0   1           2           3
1   1           2           4
2   1           2           3
3   1           2           5
4   1           2           3
5   1           2           4
```

```py
group1['first such row'] = group1.groupby(list(group1.columns))[group1.columns[0]
                                                               ].transform('idxmin')    
group1
```

```py
    column 1    column 2    column 3    first such row
0   1           2           3           0
1   1           2           4           1
2   1           2           3           0
3   1           2           5           3
4   1           2           3           0
5   1           2           4           1
```

Comment: Thank so much Arne! works perfectly. But I don't understand how this works.. Could you explain me a little bit this part: .transform('idxmim'). Why this find the duplicates in the columns?. Anyway thanks so much!!

Comment: @FERNANDO FERNANDEZ Thanks for letting me know that it works. `transform()` is a general pandas method that works on DataFrames or Series. It takes as its first argument the name of a function to apply. In this case we pass `idxmin()`, which is yet another pandas method, and it returns the index of the first occurrence of the minimum over the values in the Series it's applied to.