# How do I get a list of the duplicate rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big data frame, with over 100 thousand variables(rows) in 358 samples.

I want to know which variables are identical (duplicated) through all samples.

A sample data frame is like:

```
         Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5
1000084  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    
1000092  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1000096  0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
1000110  0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
1000116  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

The result I need could be something like this: or a list of lists of identical rows

```
 {1000084:[1000092, 1000116], 1000096:[1000110]}
```

I tried the duplicate method from pandas, but it will leave only the unique items or the unique items plus the first or last duplicate.

I tried with this code but is taking ages:

```
duplicated_index = set()
duplicates = {}

for i, pos in enumerate(df.index, 0):
    #check if the row has marked as duplicate, if so, ignore it
    if i in duplicated_index:
        continue
    for j in range(i+1, df.shape[0]):
        if all(df.iloc[i] == df.iloc[j]):
             duplicated_index.add(j)
             tmp = duplicates.setdefault(pos, [])
             duplicates[pos].append(df.iloc[j].name)
```

Is there any more appropriate way to obtain this list and identify which rows are identical to which other?

Comment: {1000084:[1000092, 1000116], 1000096:[1000110]} what? What is the key here?

Comment: Groupby all columns.

Comment: Related: [find duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe),

Comment: You might want to choose one of the other solutions. Their execution time is not really affected by number of columns while mine scales linearly with number of columns as well as number of rows. For a (100000,300) DataFrame with **no** duplicates, theirs are faster .

Comment: @wwii, yours worked fine and was very fast too, less than a minute. Besides you had a more comprehensive, explicit and clear answer that helped me to better understand how the groupby method worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groupby all the columns; find groups with more than one item and put those in a list.  Uses a for loop.

```
>>> gb = df.groupby(df.columns.to_list())
>>> d = {}
>>> for a,b in gb:
...     if len(b) > 1:
...         d[b.index[0]] = b.index[1:].to_list()

        
>>> d
{1000084: [1000092, 1000116], 1000096: [1000110]}
>>>
```

---

Using the same groupby as above, write a function to return the index for a group and construct a dictionary using the [aggregate method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html).

```
def f(thing):
    return thing.index.to_list()

>>> {key:val for key,*val in gb.aggregate(f) if val}
{1000084: [1000092, 1000116], 1000096: [1000110]}
```

---

Looks like the execution time for this scales linearly with number of columns **and** rows (number of items).

---

Here is a large DataFrame for testing. Unfortunately it doesn't want to produce duplicate rows - maybe that is worst case for groupby then iterate?

```
import itertools,string
import numpy as np
nrows,ncols = 100000,300

a = np.random.randint(1,3,(nrows,ncols))
# or using the new random stuff
#from numpy.random import default_rng
#rng = default_rng()
#a = rng.integers(1,3,(nrows,ncols))

index = np.arange(1000000,1000000+nrows,dtype=np.int64)
cols = [''.join(thing) for thing in itertools.combinations(string.ascii_letters,3)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=a,index=index,columns=cols[:ncols])
```

Answer (score 2):

`reset_index` then `groupby` add `agg`

```
l = df.reset_index().groupby(list(df))['index'].agg(list).tolist()
Out[291]: [[1000084, 1000092, 1000116], [1000096, 1000110]]
```

Comment: Then iterate to make the dictionary. Do you have a *feel* for whether there would be a significant speed difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: Nevermind, did a quick test on a small DataFrame - similar.

Comment: Although yours does much better than mine on larger DataFrames, mine scales linearly with number of columns while yours is not affected by number of columns hardly at all.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has its own function `duplicated()`that would return all duplicated rows.

```
duplicated_rows = df[df.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], keep=False)]
```

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html),

- `subset` can be a list of your selected columns which need to be checked for duplicates. By default, it uses all columns.
- `keep` is set to `False` to keep **all** occurrences.

If you want the result as a list of lists, may be a little modification of code you drafted above would probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another approach with `pd.factorize` and `Index.groupby`

```
idx = pd.factorize(list(map(tuple,df.to_numpy().tolist())))[0]

d = {g[0]: [*g[1:]] for _,g in df.index.groupby(idx).items() if len(g)>1}
```

---

```
{1000084: [1000092, 1000116], 1000096: [1000110]}
```

Or with `df.to_records()` but it can be slower then the previous method:

```
idx = pd.factorize(df.to_records(index=False))[0]
d = {g[0]: [*g[1:]] for _,g in df.index.groupby(idx).items() if len(g)>1}
```

Comment: Final dictionary includes *rows* with no duplicates - don't know if OP cares.

Comment: @wwii Thank you for pointing, should be fixed now :)