# How to 'write-back' the result of an aggregation to the main data frame

Tags: python, pandas

**Note**: this question is similar to this one: [find duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe), which already has a great answer. However, I'd like to focus on the 'second half' of this question here which discusses the best way to write back the "duplicate-group" into the main data frame.

---

I have data that looks like this:

```
file            md5
myfile.mov      9ee8
teller.mov      2udi
seven.mov       9ee8
```

And I want to great a new field called `dupe_md5_group` that is the md5 if there is a count(*) > 1 and None otherwise. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame([{'file': 'myfile.mov', 'md5': '9ee8'}, {'file': 'teller.mov', 'md5': '2udi'}, {'file': 'seven.mov', 'md5': '9ee8'}])

# get all the duplicate md5s as a set which we can later look up
duplicate_md5s = set(df2[['md5']].groupby('md5').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).md5)

# write back the duplicate results to the main dataframe with a new column if a dupe
df2['dupe_md5_group'] = df2['md5'].apply(lambda md5: None if md5 not in duplicate_md5s else md5)

#          file   md5           dupe_md5_group
# 0  myfile.mov  9ee8           9ee8
# 1  teller.mov  2udi           None
# 2   seven.mov  9ee8           9ee8
```

It works, however it seems super heavy-handed. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180983/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @RichieV sort of -- yes it addresses the first of the two statements. But not really the write-back at all. Actually the answer really just removes all the other rows, so I think this question is slightly different though yes, I can change it and reference that if you'll re-open it.

Comment: you question is still open, that was just a suggestion.. but it does explain how to solve this with `series.duplicated()` take a look at `series.where` for the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with duplicated.

```
df['dupe_md5_group'] = np.where(df['md5'].duplicated(keep=False), df['md5'], None)

         file   md5 dupe_md5_group
0  myfile.mov  9ee8           9ee8
1  teller.mov  2udi           None
2   seven.mov  9ee8           9ee8
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Also much more efficient than the suggested duplicate.